# Excel: How to list out matching items in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

So, I have a list of Chinese characters. When I hover over a character, I would like a pop-up box to display showing me all the entries in a separate list which contain that character somewhere in it. Sounds simple...

To achieve this, my thought process is something like this:

1. Create a parallel list of cells which contains the output (i.e. a few columns over, so all characters and answers are relatively positioned) using arrays which do the lookup work.
2. Create a rollover effect so that the contents of each relative cell is shown when the mouse hovers over the character.

Part 2 seems relatively simple using:
https://optionexplicitvba.com/2011/04/09/how-to-create-a-rollover-effect-in-excel-execute-a-macro-when-your-mouse-is-over-a-cell/
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315709/excel-cell-values-into-comments

However, the issue is getting the output of an array to show in a single cell with a line-break (i.e. return key) between them. I have looked at using

```
=INDEX(List, SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Search_strings), List)), "", ROW(List)-MIN(ROW(List))+1), ROW(List)-MIN(ROW(List))+1)=ROWS(Search_strings), ROW(List), ""), ROW(A1)))
```

but this only shows the output over a number of rows. Does anyone know how this kind of single-cell output could be achieved?!

Many thanks!

Update: So..., a copy of the file I am using can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vOgBslu670RL67fh3YkrEJ_xAD2ZZNOC/view?usp=sharing
On tab 'Chart', you can see the Chinese characters (coloured using conditional formatting per exam level, using a vlookup condition to tab 'Data' columns A and B).
I would like to be able to hover over a character and a pop-up show which contains all the instances of that character in cells 'Chart'!D:D. So, for example, the pop-up for the character 安 would show:
安静 - ānjìng

安居乐业 - ānjū lèyè

安宁 - ānníng

安排 - ānpái

安全 - ānquán

安慰 - ānwèi

安详 - ānxiáng

安置 - ānzhì

安装 - ānzhuāng

不安 - bùān

公安局 - gōngān jú

一路平安 - yílù píngān

治安 - zhìān

My thought was to create a single-cell array of all the instances and then call up that content in a pop-up upon hover using a macro. Alternatively (and I'm not sure if this would be easier or if it is even possible) for a macro to do the looking up and the pop-up creation in one. Doing it all in one is a bit beyond my abilities, so am avoiding that for the moment and heading towards step 1 instead! However, if anyone is able to point me in the right direction, I would be very happy to get to work! :-)

Comment: Please provide a data sample that can be applied to test your formula. Edit your question to do that. Do NOT do that in a comment. Once you have edited your question, post a comment to alert your followers.

Comment: I can suggest you how to show the matching items as comments when you mouse over the cell,, will it works for you?

Comment: Updated - hope this makes more sense! :-)

Comment: I can suggest you VBA solution will allow you to pop up all the instance of value/cell as Comment. Like State and their cities or a word and it's synonyms while mouse over.